# SED code for removing newline

Tags: sed

I am looking for sed command which will transform following line:

```
>AT1G01020.6 | ARV1 family protein | Chr1:6788-8737 REVERSE LENGTH=944 | 201606
AGACCCGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGA
GAGAGAGAGCAATGGCGGCGAGTGAACACAGATGCGTGGGATGTGGTTTTAGGGTAAAGT
CATTGTTCATTCAATACTCTCCGGGGAAATTGCAAGGAAGTAGCAGATGAGTACATCGAG
TGTGAACGCATGATTATTTTCATCGATTTAATCCTTCACAGACCAAAGGTATATAGACAC
```

into

```
>AT1G01020.6 | ARV1 family protein | Chr1:6788-8737 REVERSE LENGTH=944 | 201606
AGACCCGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGCAATGGCGGCGAGTGAACACAGATGCGTGGGATGTGGTTTTAGGGTAAAGTCATTGTTCATTCAATACTCTCCGGGGAAATTGCAAGGAAGTAGCAGATGAGTACATCGAGTGTGAACGCATGATTATTTTCATCGATTTAATCCTTCACAGACCAAAGGTATATAGACAC
```

which means newline after `>` this character will remain unchanged, while on other cases newlines will be joined.

I have tried with the following line, but it is not working:

```
sed s/^!>\n$// <in.fasta>out.fasta
```

I have a 28MB fasta file which I need to transform.

Comment: All AT1G line starts with ">" character. It is missed in my question.

Comment: I would assume you wouldn't want to remove the newline before the next `>` either.

Comment: `!` *in a regex* matches a literal exclamation mark, I guess you mean something like `sed '/^>/!s/\n//'`

Comment: What is the program that requires the sequence data to be on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is not a particularly good tool for this.

```
awk '/^>/ { if(prev) printf "\n"; print; next }
    { printf "%s", $0; prev = 1; }
    END { if(prev) printf "\n" }' in.fasta >out.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^>/{print (l?l ORS:"") $0;l="";next}{l=l $0}END{print l}' file
```

The line is printed if a `>` or the end of the file is reached, otherwise the line is buffered in the variable `l`.

Comment: If the sequences are really long, buffering them in memory is a bit problematic. I guess they are not in practice long enough that this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you here. Without using any array or variable's values solution.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""} /^>/{if(FNR==1){print $0 RS} else {print RS $0 RS};next}1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""} /^>/{printf("%s",FNR==1?$0 RS:RS $0 RS);next}1' Input_file
```